# SQL Boolean column value

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to alter the following column. The syntax I currently have is as follows

```
ALTER TABLE
mark_tmp_cars
ALTER COLUMN
dataflag 
bit Not NULL
DEFAULT 0
```

however it won't work with the default value of 0

Comment: `DEFAULT` is a constraint. You can't use `ALTER COLUMN` to add such a constraint. What is the existing definition of `dataflag`?

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue by using the following
ALTER TABLE
mark_tmp_cars
ADD  
"dataflag"
bit DEFAULT 0

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
ALTER TABLE mark_tmp_cars
ADD dataflag  BIT NOT NULL  
CONSTRAINT dataflag_zero DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES
```